# Call converter depending on two values

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

i'm trying to get a value depending two values, in my listbox i'm trying to do somthing like this :

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Distance" Text="{Binding lattitude,Longtitude,Converter={StaticResource Distanceconverter}}" />
```

so, actually the problem that i need to call my converter but depending in 2 values,
 any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, change to what you are binding to the following:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Distance" Text="{Binding Path=.,Converter={StaticResource Distanceconverter}}" />
```

And change your `DistanceConverter` to accept the object which contains both the latitude and longitude. Multi binding is not currently supported in Windows Phone.

At the top of your page, add:

```
  <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <converters:Distanceconverter x:Key="Distanceconverter" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Assuming your binding model looks like:

```
public class LocationModel
{
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

Create a converter in the form of

```
public class DistanceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var location = value as LocationModel;

        if (location != null)
        {
            // Your business logic here, e.g.
            return location.Latitude + location.Latitude;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have to use the 2 parameteres to get the value, i can't unterstand yout answer can you explain forther please?

Comment: Extract those two parameters directly in the converter. I mean, you wrote the converter and you can cast the input object to your view model and extract both the latitude and longitude directly.

Comment: my problem is that i need to call a webservice with restclient in the convert function using locations parameters which has a return to another function in parsing !

Comment: Don't do that, converter converts from one value to another. If you need to call an asynchronous function, do it in your viewmodel and once you are done, update view model properties.

Comment: i couldn't found a way to do that can you help me with an example pleaseN